# Whitelisted Twitter Sign In still cannot get email

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, authentication, twitter-oauth

I have already requested to whitelist my app to get user permission

[image]

I am using the same client key and client secret after this but I still encountered:

`**TW ERROR: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=37 "Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform." UserInfo=0x7fa3cb9e0df0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.}`

Here is my code:

```
let twitterInstance = Twitter.sharedInstance()
twitterInstance.startWithConsumerKey(TwitterClientKey, consumerSecret: TwitterClientSecret)

twitterInstance.logInWithCompletion {
    (session, error) -> Void in
    if (session != nil) {
        println("signed in as \(session.userName)");

        if (twitterInstance.session() != nil) {
            if let shareEmailViewController = TWTRShareEmailViewController(completion: {
                (email: String!, error: NSError!) in
                print("TW EMAIL: \(email)")
                if (email != nil) {
                    print("TW EMAIL: \(email)")
                } else {
                    print("TW ERROR: \(error)")
                }
            }) {
                self.presentViewController(shareEmailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("User not logged in")
        }


    } else {
        println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get email id of user? I am also facing same problem .Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

To get user email address, your application should be whitelisted. Here is the [link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email). Go to [use this form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform). You can either send mail to `sdk-feedback@twitter.com` with some details about your App like Consumer key, App Store link of an App, Link to privacy policy, Metadata, Instructions on how to log into our App etc..They will respond within 2-3 working days.

Here is the story how I got whitelisted by conversation with Twitter support team:

- Send mail to `sdk-feedback@twitter.com` with some details about your App like Consumer key, App Store link of an App, Link to privacy policy, Metadata, Instructions on how to log into our App. Mention in mail that you want to access user email adress inside your App.
- They will review your App and reply to you withing 2-3 business days.
- Once they say that your App is whitelisted, update your App's settings in Twitter Developer portal. Sign in to [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com) and:

  1. On the 'Settings' tab, add a terms of service and privacy policy URL
  2. On the 'Permissions' tab, change your token's scope to request email. This option will only been seen, once your App gets whitelisted.

**Get user email address:**

```
    -(void)requestUserEmail
    {
        if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

            TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
            [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
             initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
             }];

            [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        } else {
            // Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: i had done all the things but still getting null in email